# DirectX composition issue

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com, directx

I'm trying to use DirectComposition on windows for drawing some visuals over Window and have following issue. Our application is multi plugin application and some of the windows already called **CreateTargetForHwnd** method to work with composition and now when I try to call **CreateTargetForHwnd**  over that windows getting **DCOMPOSITION_ERROR_WINDOW_ALREADY_COMPOSED** exception. Is it possible to get
IDCompositionTarget pointer if it is already created? I couldn't find such API.

Comment: have you checked the error meaning  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directcomp/directcomposition-error-codes it say the method was called with hwnd and topmost parameters for which a visual tree already exists. and if you look deeper  the second parameter of CreateTargetForHwnd is BOOL topmost  and it's documentation says it is TRUE if the visual tree should be displayed on top of the children of the window specified by the hwnd parameter; otherwise, the visual tree is displayed behind the children.

Comment: if that doesn't help produce [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If all the windows that cause this are yours, just associate their IDCompositionTarget to the HWND using some mechanism (for example SetProp https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setpropa)

Comment: @ma1169 your solution it is working but not for every case by setting topmost flag true or false allow to create two different targets. But the issue is still open if it is done for both values. I'm wondering why there is not API to get CompositionTarget for window if it is already created.

Comment: @SimonMourer no the case is that not all code part is owned by me and there is some good legacy plugin's that I didn't want to brake

Comment: If it's not your code, all bets are off, you can't play with someone else's composition target. It may well belong to an underlying framework (like Windows' XAML, etc.)